# How to launch dialer with primary contact number?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Can anyone help me achieve the following,

Given a Uri to a contact already obtained via an 'ACTION_PICK' during a previous activity, I want to launch an ACTION_DIAL intent to call the contact.

Not sure how to go about this though, do I first need to query to find the primary number associated with the contact or is there a simpler approach?  I was hoping I could just launch ACTION_DIAL with the Uri of the contact and it would figure out what to do itself but that doesn't work.

Your advice as always is appreciated.

PS This code is for Froyo onwards, so using ContactsContract not the older stuff.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for the benefit of others, launching ACTION_DIAL/ACTION_CALL intent with the URI for a contact obtained from an ACTION_PICK intent does not work.  It's an invalid parameter.

So I had to determine the phone number for the contact via a couple of queries.  I also only look for the 'Primary' telephone.

My code to do the task is as follows, Perhaps I don't need to do the initial query to obtain the ID as I have the URI already but I haven't figured out an alternative yet so if anyone can suggest otherwise please let me know :-) ,

```
// passing in String uri - obtained via contacts based ACTION_PICK 
        String contactId = null;
        Cursor contactCursor =  callingActivity.managedQuery(Uri.parse(uri), null, null, null, null); 
        if (contactCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            contactId =
                contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        } 

        Cursor c = callingActivity.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
          Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                  + "' AND " + Phone.IS_PRIMARY + " != 0",
          new String[] {contactId}, null);


        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER));
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "GOT PHONE : "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER)) + ","
                    +c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.LABEL)) + ","
                    +c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE)));
        }
```

[*www.dbws.net*](http://www.dbws.net)

Answer (score 2):

it will help you,

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
            Log.v("phno",""+phNo);
           myintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +phNo ));  
           myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(myintent);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't yet have the telephone number, only the Uri to a contact at this stage

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

in Manifest file